# In SQL Server, can you have multiple statements after the 'THEN' in a case statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to have a case statement in the form of:

```
CASE
    WHEN condition1 THEN result1 --And also execute this stored procedure
    WHEN condition2 THEN result2 --And also set this other variable
    ELSE result --And also execute this stored procedure
END;
```

Is there any way to do this? Otherwise I would have to break this down into a bunch of IF statements where I set a variable, and then execute the other statement, and then at the end select the variable, which seems annoying considering that most programming languages allow you to do multiple things for each case in switch statements.

Comment: You cannot execute a stored procedure from a `select` so the question is meaningless.  Perhaps you just want a T-SQL block with `IF`.

Comment: SQL Server does not support CASE statement, only CASE expression.

Comment: If you need to replicate the logic of a `Case` (`Switch`) statement, you need to use `IF...ELSE`

Comment: T-SQL only grudgingly qualifies as a programming language. Not having a proper switch statement is honestly the least of its problems. Even in an `IF .. ELSE`, you will find you need `BEGIN .. END` to group statement blocks.

Answer (score 1):

CASE is a TSQL expression. What you want to achieve can be achieved in a circuitous way. Not in straightforward manner. sample code for your reference.

```sql
DECLARE @stmt VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @stmt = (SELECT
CASE
    WHEN condition1 THEN 'Execute SPName' --And also execute this stored procedure
    WHEN condition2 THEN 'DECLARE @s INT;SET @s=3;'  --And also set this other variable
    ELSE 'Execute SPName2' --And also execute this stored procedure
END);

EXEC sp_Executesql @stmt
```

Comment: No need for a `select`, just `set @stmt = case ... end;`. Or `select @stmt = case ... end;` without `set`. Note that declaring a variable in dynamic SQL will not make it available in the scope of the code that creates the dynamic SQL.

Comment: I agree the select or set clause are a little redundant but it still demonstrates how case can be used within MS SQL.  Good on ya.

Comment: @HABO, yes. agree with you. declaring variables does not make sense. I just wanted to showcase that what the OP wanted can be achieved circuitous way

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do would look something like this:

```
IF condition 
BEGIN 
EXEC this_procedure;
END
IF another_condition;
BEGIN
EXEC this_other_procedure;
END
```

And so on for every condition.

Comment: By not using `else` this could allow multiple code blocks to execute. Just sayin'.

Comment: That's what I feared. I'm trying to edit a case statement with 66 cases, and it looks like I need to rewrite the entire thing as a series of if/else blocks

Comment: If you need to add an ELSE you can do that but you have to nest it between BEGIN and END.  But SQL will stop evaluating everything else.

Answer (score -2):

SQL Supports a case statement.  You can do what you suggest. Just embed the case statement into a select statement.  https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp

Comment: Although it took a long time for M$ to come around, they did correct their documentation to call [`case`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) an _expression_,  not a _statement_. That W3S doesn't use terminology accurately doesn't make it true. A _statement_ can be executed, e.g. try running `case when 1=0 then 'Foo' else 'Bar' end;`. How does that work? How do you use a statement block ([`begin`/`end`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/begin-end-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)) in an expression?

Comment: I've been developing SQL applications for 20 years. It's been around at least since MS SQL 2000.  I'm really confused why your highlighting the semantics between an expression and a statement.  You can use the case statement on scalar variables within SQL like Venkataraman R suggested or on a set of records within a select clause like I suggested.  

Here's the MS SQL Documentation for this expression
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: [Statements](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/statements?view=sql-server-ver15) ≠ [Expressions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/expressions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Yes, the [SS2000 Documentation](https://www.sqlserverscience.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/SQL2000_release.pdf) freely uses "CASE expression", "CASE function" and "CASE statement". They were wrong and have cleaned up the current documentation. (Around the time the first paper was published by the ACM describing SEQUEL I was starting to write commercial software.)